# How to Detect Blocks That is Not Air

Tags: minecraft-commands

I am trying to make a command line that armor stands is moving and if armorstand is touching a block they say block! and the real question is how can I detect a block that is not air ?

Comment: Can you share what you have tried so far? This works best when you show some effort. And your effort shows the community the direction you are trying to go.

Comment: Flagging question as unclear because it does not specify which edition is being played.

Comment: Please see [What to do before asking a minecraft-commands question?](https://gaming.meta.stackexchange.com/q/13507/4797)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I assume you want to test the block below the armor stand, otherwise just adjust the command to the coordinates you need.

You tag it if there is air:

```
/execute @e[type=armor_stand] ~ ~ ~ detect ~ ~-1 ~  air 0 scoreboard players tag @s add air
```

Then you test for the tag in the output command:

```
/execute @e[type=armor_stand,tag=!air] ~ ~ ~ say block!
```

Then you clear it again for the next round:

```
/scoreboard players tag @e[type=armor_stand] remove air
```

---

In 1.13 and above, you can simply invert the condition:

```
/execute at @e[type=armor_stand] unless block ~ ~-1 ~ air run say block!
```